# R: How to compare 2 matrices

Tags: r, if-statement, matrix

I have 2 matrices

1. matrix1 (nrow=3, ncol=3)
2. matrix2 (nrow=5, ncol=5)

I know how to compare and replace conditionnaly an element of a matrix by an element of another matrix, but ONLY if these 2 elements are sharing the same [i,j] like this :

```
ifelse(matrix1<0.5, matrix2[,], matrix1[,])
```

## Question:

Here I'd like to replace an element of matrix1, by an element of matrix2 of **another column** like this:

*If* matrix1[i,j]<0.5  *Then* I want to replace it be matrix2[i,j+2]
*Else* I want to replace it be matrix2[i,j+1]

The problem is:

- I can't use loop because of performance
- I don't know how to explain to ifelse to move on another column.

**How can I do this kind of comparaison efficiently on big matrix ?**

*Here is the data:*

```
> dput(matrix1)
structure(c(0.782534098718315, 0.279918688116595, 0.139927505282685, 
0.485497816000134, 0.150636059232056, 0.976677459431812, 0.101831247797236, 
0.491994257550687, 0.492571017006412), .Dim = c(3L, 3L))

> dput(matrix2)
structure(1:25, .Dim = c(5L, 5L))
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output as the `j+3` may create Error subscript out of bounds.

Comment: The number of columns in the second matrix is not consistent with what you want to do. But if is was, I would try first something like `ifelse(a < 0.5, b[1:3,1:3+2], b[1:3,1:3+3])`...

Comment: I made a mistake it's j+1 instead of j+3.

Comment: @Ophelie Could you show the expected output.  It is confusing.

Comment: You might try to manipulate the matrices accordingly so that you have a one-to-one match between elements in "matrix1" and "matrix2"; i.e. something like `ifelse(matrix1 < 0.5, matrix2[seq_len(nrow(matrix1)), -c(1, 2)], matrix2[seq_len(nrow(matrix1)), -c(1, 5)])`, although I'm not sure how generalisable this could be..

Comment: @CathG Perhaps I coded wrong as alexis_laz is getting the result what you showed

Answer (score 3):

Here `m1` and `m2` are the two matrices.  Based on @alexis_laz comments, you could try

```
indx1 <- tail(seq(ncol(m1)+1),ncol(m1))
indx2 <-  tail(seq(ncol(m1)+2),ncol(m1))
rowInd <- 1:nrow(m1)
ifelse(m1 < 0.5, m2[rowInd,indx2], m2[rowInd, indx1])
#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    6   16   21
#[2,]   12   17   22
#[3,]   13   13   23
```

Or you can create `index` by

```
 indx <- cbind(c(row(m1)), c(col(m1)))
 indx1 <- cbind(indx[,1], indx[,2]+1)
 indx2 <- cbind(indx[,1], indx[,2]+2)
 ifelse(m1 < 0.5, m2[indx2], m2[indx1])
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 #[1,]    6   16   21
 #[2,]   12   17   22
 #[3,]   13   13   23
```

Comment: I may misunderstood the question but I don't think your output is what you're supposed to get (I think first line for example is supposed to be `6 16 21`). Although I don't really understand why...

Comment: @CathG What is first line? row or column?  My code is based on the index that the OP showed.  If `m1 < 0.5`, then `j+2` else `j+1` for those matching entries.

Comment: first row (where you get `7 17 23`) : there is no 7, 17 or 23 on the first row of matrix2

Comment: @CathG It is based on `j+1` and `j+2` ie. column's 1 greater or 2 greater than those matching.

Comment: @CathG Okay, then, may be I am wrong. I will delete

Comment: yes I know and found your code rather brilliant but, still, the first row of your ouput is `7 17 23` and there is no 7, 17 or 23 on the first row of matrix2... there must be only a slight modification to do...

Comment: @CathG Thanks for your comments.  I was totally wrong previously as I misunderstood the question.